# How to Claims mapping in AD B2C custom policy when using SAML IDP

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying to add an SAML IDP to AD B2C using custom policy, did all setup and B2C redirecting me to IDP's login page. But now I'm confused with the claims mapping step. I'm following the below article,

[Set up sign-up and sign-in with SAML identity provider using Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-saml?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#map-the-claims)

[This](https://samltest.id/download/) is one showing the attributes sent by the IDP. My technical profile is added below:

```
<TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Contoso-SAML2">
      <DisplayName>Saml Test</DisplayName>
      <Description>Login with your SAML identity provider account</Description>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="PartnerEntity"> https://samltest.id/saml/idp</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SAMLSigningCert"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="uid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="sn" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"  PartnerClaimType="mail"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="samltest.id" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Saml-idp"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

After completing the sign in I'm getting below error:

> AADB2C: A claim with id 'issuerUserId' was not found, which is required by ClaimsTransformation 'CreateAlternativeSecurityId' with id 'CreateAlternativeSecurityId' in policy 'B2C_1A_signup_signin'

I believe this is because, I haven't done the claims mapping. How can I resolve this?

Comment: issuerUserId must be null’ which would only happen if nothing mapped to Uid in the SAML response. Post an example SAML response from the IdP and we can help do the claim mapping config.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Hope this is what you are asked for https://easyupload.io/t0ukw2

Comment: I suspect we are targeting attribute name (<saml:Attribute Name=\"urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.7\" ) and not friendlyname.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT That worked, I was confused with that name, was not sure about giving the partnerclaimtype as "urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.7". Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue solved with the help of [Jas Suri - MSFT's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8357357/jas-suri-msft) comment. Below was my SAML response,

```xml
<saml:Assertion xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ID="_134d0c388282ca18031a7d00efffa0fc" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2022-04-29T08:34:35.635Z" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
  <saml:Issuer>https://samltest.id/saml/idp</saml:Issuer>
  <saml:Subject>
    <saml:NameID NameQualifier="https://samltest.id/saml/idp" SPNameQualifier="https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent">V3QCBLSO2CHF47EMELCG23VN73FLI6ZY</saml:NameID>
    <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
      <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2022-04-29T08:39:35.646Z" Recipient="https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase/samlp/sso/assertionconsumer" InResponseTo="_c6e2e6b1-518f-4837-9e3e-8e7a0fd6d857" Address="157.46.147.227" />
    </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
  </saml:Subject>
  <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2022-04-29T08:34:35.635Z" NotOnOrAfter="2022-04-29T08:39:35.635Z">
    <saml:AudienceRestriction>
      <saml:Audience>https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase</saml:Audience>
    </saml:AudienceRestriction>
  </saml:Conditions>
  <saml:AuthnStatement SessionIndex="_ac852acc6d8309dfb667e66ddf371620" AuthnInstant="2022-04-29T08:33:50.718Z">
    <saml:SubjectLocality Address="157.46.147.227" />
    <saml:AuthnContext>
      <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </saml:AuthnContext>
  </saml:AuthnStatement>
  <saml:AttributeStatement>
    <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.7" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="eduPersonEntitlement">
      <saml:AttributeValue>urn:mace:dir:entitlement:common-lib-terms</saml:AttributeValue>
    </saml:Attribute>
    <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="uid">
      <saml:AttributeValue>rick</saml:AttributeValue>
    </saml:Attribute>
    <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:attribute:subject-id" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
      <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">rsanchez@samltest.id</saml:AttributeValue>
    </saml:Attribute>
    <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:2.5.4.20" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="telephoneNumber">
      <saml:AttributeValue>+1-555-555-5515</saml:AttributeValue>
    </saml:Attribute>
    <saml:Attribute Name="https://samltest.id/attributes/role" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="role">
      <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">manager@Samltest.id</saml:AttributeValue>
    </saml:Attribute>
    <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="mail">
      <saml:AttributeValue>rsanchez@samltest.id</saml:AttributeValue>
    </saml:Attribute>
    <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:2.5.4.4" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="sn">
      <saml:AttributeValue>Sanchez</saml:AttributeValue>
    </saml:Attribute>
    <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.241" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="displayName">
      <saml:AttributeValue>Rick Sanchez</saml:AttributeValue>
    </saml:Attribute>
    <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:2.5.4.42" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="givenName">
      <saml:AttributeValue>Rick</saml:AttributeValue>
    </saml:Attribute>
  </saml:AttributeStatement>
</saml:Assertion>
```

I used the friendly name for the **PartnerClaimtype** in my custom policy technical profile instead of name. I changed the technical profile as below and it worked perfectly.

```xml
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Contoso-SAML2">
      <DisplayName>Saml Test</DisplayName>
      <Description>Login with your SAML identity provider account</Description>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="PartnerEntity"> https://samltest.id/saml/idp</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SAMLSigningCert"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="urn:oid:2.5.4.42" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="urn:oid:2.5.4.4" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.241" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"  PartnerClaimType="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="samltest.id" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Saml-idp"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Thanks Jas Suri.

Answer (score 0):

•   As per the error that you are encountering, your `<ClaimsProvider>` is missing the `‘socialIdpUserId’` claim. This is because either the `<OutputClaim>` entry which has a **ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdPUserId"** is missing or it's mapped to a `PartnerClaimType` that your SAML IdP isn't providing. Thus, from the documentation link that you are referencing below, I would suggest you use the below modified **‘Technical Profile’** element in your custom policy: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-saml?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#map-the-claims

```
<TechnicalProfiles>
<TechnicalProfile Id="Contoso-SAML2">
  <DisplayName>Saml Test</DisplayName>
  <Description>Login with your SAML identity provider account</Description>
  <Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="PartnerEntity"> https://samltest.id/saml/idp</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SAMLSigningCert"/>
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="userId"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="givenName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="sn" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"  PartnerClaimType="mail"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="samltest.id" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Saml-idp"/>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

The above changes in the technical profile of your custom policy should help you resolve your error.

Comment: I don't have a claim 'socialIdpUserId'

Comment: You may not have a claim named 'socialIdpUserId' but you might have to edit the corresponding output claim used by you earlier, i.e., 'issuerUserId' to this one as then the 'CreateAlternativeSecurityID' claims transformation would work. I would suggest you try doing this.